# How to parse a string into a code structure with TemplateHaskell?

Tags: templates, haskell

Right now, I have the following piece of code in my project:

```
embedNarration :: String -> Q Exp
embedNarration file = 
    let text = unsafePerformIO $ readFile file
        parsedMaybe = parseNarration  text
        succ x = case x of
          Left x -> throw $ ErrorCall x
          Right x' -> x'
        parsed = succ parsedMaybe
        res = do parser <- [|((fromRight undefined) . parseNarration)|]
                 d <- return $ seq parsed text
                 return $ AppE parser $! LitE $! StringL d
    in res
```

Which is jury-rigged from Data.FileEmbed module's source code. The intention of the code is to generate a Narration (which is a data structure defined in-code) from a resource file.

Right now this quite ugly piece that I don't fully understand tries to parse the resource file; throws a compile-time error if the parse is unsuccessful; or, if the parse is successful, embeds the following piece into the source code:

```
((fromRight undefined) . parseNarration $ "THE ENTIRE RESOURCE FILE")
```

Where parseNarration is a function `:: String -> Either String Narration`

The problem here is the double parsing - the resource file is parsed once during compile time to ensure it's valid, and then the second time during runtime from a string literal. Ideally, I want to, instead of a string literal and a call to the parser, for TemplateHaskell to directly substitute a Narration, so that the parser would only exist during compile-time. But I have no idea how to do this. Surface-level guides to TemplateHaskell and trying to jury-rigg the code further haven't been successful. Is it possible to do? If yes, how?

Comment: A simple solution that still requires some runtime deserialisation is to emit a `StringL` of the result of `show` on `parsed`, and emit a call to `read` rather than `parseNarration`. It’d be better to directly emit the Haskell code that would construct `parsed` itself (i.e., the result of `Show`, but not serialised as a string)—you could easily write a function `Narration -> Q Exp` that generates that, but I don’t know offhand how to do so conveniently/generically.

Comment: Also you don’t need `unsafePerformIO` here, there’s [`runIO :: IO a -> Q a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.15.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:runIO) for embedding I/O in splices.